# Get the data without grouping asset_id in the query

Tags: laravel, foreach

I have the data like below in my table:
[image]

The query which I am using to get the results :

```
$prices = BundlePrice::where('bundle_id',4)->get()->groupBy("asset_id");
                foreach($prices as $bundleprice) {   
                    $price = collect($bundleprice)->where("price_id",2)->first();
                    $default = collect($bundleprice)->where("price_id",1)->first();
                    if (empty($price) && empty($default)) { continue; }
                    if (empty($default)) {
                        $default = $price;
                    }
                    $weekam =  !empty($price->weekday_am)?$price->weekday_am:$default->weekday_am;
                    $weekpm = !empty($price->weekday_pm)?$price->weekday_pm:$default->weekday_pm;
                    $nonweekam = !empty($price->weekend_am)?$price->weekend_am:$default->weekend_am;
                    $nonweekpm = !empty($price->weekend_pm)?$price->weekend_pm:$default->weekend_pm;
                    $primaryArray[] = ['asset_id' => $default->asset_id,'weekam' => $weekam,'weekpm' => $weekpm,'nonweekam' => $nonweekam,'nonweekpm' => $nonweekpm];        
                }
```

And the output from the above query is :

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 250.00
    "weekpm" => 120.00
    "nonweekam" => 110.00
    "nonweekpm" => 130.00
  ]
]
```

But the output I want should be like below :

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 250.00
    "weekpm" => 120.00
    "nonweekam" => 110.00
    "nonweekpm" => 130.00
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 200.0
    "weekpm" => 460.00
    "nonweekam" => 210.00
    "nonweekpm" => 230.00
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 300.00
    "weekpm" => 320.00
    "nonweekam" => 500.00
    "nonweekpm" => 330.00
  ]
]
```

If i do without group by `asset_id` nothing is coming .Can please someone help me to solve this ? thank you .

another way around which I tried but did not work for me

```
$data =BundlePrice::where('price_id',1)->where('bundle_id',3)->get();
                 $data2 = BundlePrice::where('price_id',2)->where('bundle_id',3)->get();
                foreach($data as $default)
                {

                    foreach($data2 as $price)
                    {

                        if($price->asset_id == $default->asset_id)
                        {

                            $weekam     = !empty($price->weekday_am)?$price->weekday_am:$default->weekday_am;
                            $weekpm     = !empty($price->weekday_pm)?$price->weekday_pm:$default->weekday_pm;
                            $nonweekam  = !empty($price->weekend_am)?$price->weekend_am:$default->weekend_am;
                            $nonweekpm  = !empty($price->weekend_pm)?$price->weekend_pm:$default->weekend_pm;

                            $primaryArray[$default->id] = ['asset_id' => $price->asset_id,'weekam' => $weekam,'weekpm' => $weekpm,'nonweekam' => $nonweekam,'nonweekpm' => $nonweekpm]; 

                        }  


                    }


                }
```

But the output is coming with all last row prices.

```
array:3 [▼
  39 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 100.0
    "weekpm" => 120.0
    "nonweekam" => 500.0
    "nonweekpm" => 130.0
  ]
  40 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 200.0
    "weekpm" => 220.0
    "nonweekam" => 500.0
    "nonweekpm" => 230.0
  ]
  41 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 300.0
    "weekpm" => 320.0
    "nonweekam" => 500.0
    "nonweekpm" => 330.0
  ]
]
```

But it's repeating the same values for all the array values.Please suggest me any solution?

Comment: You should get a Collection of Collections as the return of `groupBy`, so, you should have two `foreach` statements to get the actual model object.

Comment: @Laerte : I did not get you can you explain me more clear ?

Comment: `$prices` should be a Collection with several Collections inside it. Each one will have a group of `BundlePrice` objects. So, in the foreach in your code, you will have a Collection as `$bundleprice` variable. So, you would need to have another `foreach` to get the actual object.

Comment: Okay got you . At the first time i have tried the way you suggested me then it was returning only array with last array values. then  i have done something like this even this did not work for me.